# How does a fluid float on another fluid?

Tags: fluid-statics

Consider two immiscible fluids. If the fluid with less density is poured into the fluid with more density, they will separate as layers. Thus, the fluid with less density floats with its entire volume above the denser fluid. Therefore, the upthrust on it is zero.

$U = ρgV$;

$U$ is the  magnitude of upthrust;

$g$ is acceleration due to gravity;

$V$ is volume of test substance immersed in fluid;

**Question:-**

How does the rarer fluid float on the denser fluid even if the upthrust on it is zero?

It must sink because of its weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the less dense fluid has settled on top of the more dense fluid, the less dense fluid is subject to three vertical forces:

a downward force due to the pressure of the atmosphere and a downward force due to gravitational attraction of the Earth,

the sum of which as up to

the upward force due the pressure at the top of the more dense fluid.

This is really not much different to a portion of fluid "floating" on top of fluid of the same type underneath it, ie the upper part of a column of water on top of the lower part of the column of water.

Comment: It all comes down to the ability of fluid to maintain its structure and provide support. If the fluid above it is denser it can no longer support it and it falls down.

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine a tiny droplet of the upper fluid attempting to fall downward into the denser fluid. It would immediately experience an "up thrust" proportional to its volume, and be pushed upward to rejoin the rest.

So the whole upper fluid is held in equilibrium by this against falling,  and never gets a chance to form downward droplets.

Answer (score 0):

The buoyancy force increases when the volume of rarer fluid increases. Buoyancy force just depends upon the density (Check the formula you provided in the question once. That formula answers your question).

Take the example of a ship. The ship is so heavy. Then how does it float on water?
Because the buoyancy force is higher than the weight force.